# Change the center point of leaflet

Tags: leaflet

By default zoom to, setview functions show the center point of the map in the center point of div measured by pixel of browser. I want to show the center at slightly right when left panel is visible. In http://2gis.ru/ site, they used the similar function. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably be interested in one of those plugins:

- [Leaflet-active-area](https://github.com/Mappy/Leaflet-active-area)

  > This plugin allows you to use a smaller portion of the map as an active area. All positioning methods (setView, fitBounds, setZoom) will be applied on this portion instead of the all map.
- [Leaflet.ControlledBounds](https://github.com/MazeMap/Leaflet.ControlledBounds)

  > Inspired by Leaflet-active-area, automatically detects the largest area of the map not covered by any map controls and applies setView, fitBounds, setZoom, getBounds to that area.